# Which version of liquid dll suits for silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I am novice to Silverlight technology and started working with liquid menu item example. But couldn't make reference with liquid DLL with my Silverlight application. Please advice me  how to do this and which version of liquid DLL best suits for Siverlight 5. Any help highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you search for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Liquid* libraries are developed for *Silverlight 4* and should be more or less completely applicable to *Silverlight 5*.

You should be able to reference the most recent *Liquid* version, i.e. 5.3.3, for which both binaries and source code can be downloaded from the [Vectorlight web site](http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight/downloads.aspx) (registration required). If you want to use the menu functionality, reference the `Liquid.Menu` DLL in your application.